# How to merge multiple QuerySets in django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-queryset

I have following models

```
class Molecule(models.Model):
    mid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    mol_name = models.CharField(max_length=2023, blank=True, null=True)

class Pubchem(models.Model):
    molecule = models.OneToOneField('Molecule', primary_key=True, db_column='mid')
    pnum = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

in the views.py, I am trying to get Query Set which has mid, mol_name and if pnum available.

```
querySet1 = Molecule.objects.all()

querySet1 = querySet1.filter(
            Q(mol_name__istartswith=currentInitial) |
            Q(mol_name__istartswith=currentInitial.lower()) 
            ).distinct('mol_name')

querySet2 = Pubchem.objects.filter(molecule__mol_name__istartswith=currentInitial).select_related('molecule').order_by('molecule')
```

in the querySet2 not all molecules are included, which don't have entries in Pubchem they are ignored. What should be improved in either querySet1 or querySet2 to get all the required information in querySet? Or merging them is better option? if so how?

Comment: I tried to use chain but it makes 2 different types of models into one queryset and not usable for pagination. Also there will be duplicates need to remove them

Comment: I also tried to use the Value() annotation by adding a column but did not worked.

Comment: Also tried content framework method but was too complicated I felt there should be better way. However did not worked

Comment: First comment: `istartswith` is case-insensitive, so I don't know why you use a `Q` object here. Second, can you give examples of what exactly your current example is doing that you don't want?

Comment: First: Yes you are right it is not required in this case I was trying something different and just left it like that. It will not make difference right?

Second: If you see this link: https://dpaste.de/WGjV#L3,4,10,12,13 which are marked in yellow are missing in QuerySet2 as they don't have pnum entries in Pubchem. But I need those results also in the end set I need mid, mol_name and if pnum available

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is:

```
molecules = Molecule.objects.filter(
        mol_name__startswith=currentInitial
    ).select_related('pubchem')

#and now you have all molecules and some of them may have pubchems.
for molecule in molecules:
    print (molecule, molecule.pubchem.pnum if hasattr(molecule, 'pubchem') else None)
```

Comment: This works but the result set is not QuerySet is that also possible to make?

Comment: `molecules` is a QuerySet, I'm just iterating it to show you how to access the `pnum` data from a `molecule` object.